# Problem displaying Item column data in my application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm encountering an issue displaying the Item column data in the `Payments Received` report on Perfex CRM. Despite implementing code, the data isn't being displayed. Any insights into what might be causing this issue?

Below is the code I attempted for my `Reports.php` class to display Item column.

```
public function get_items($invoice_id){
    $this->db->select('tblitemable.id, tblitemable.rel_id, tblitemable.rel_type, tblitemable.qty, tblitemable.description');
    $this->db->where('rel_type', 'invoice');
    $this->db->where('rel_id', $invoice_id);
    $this->db->join(db_prefix() . 'items', '' . db_prefix() . 'items.id = ' . db_prefix() . 'itemable.item_order', 'left');
    $result= $this->db->get(db_prefix().'itemable')->result_array();

    $items= '<ul>';
   // var_dump($result); die;
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $items.='<li>'. $item['description'].' ( QTY='.(int)$item['qty'].')</li>';
    }
    $items.='</ul>';

   return $items;
}
```

And here is the code for the `Payments Received` function.

```
 public function payments_received()
  {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->model('currencies_model');
        $this->load->model('payment_modes_model');
        $payment_gateways = $this->payment_modes_model->get_payment_gateways(true);
        $select           = [
            db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.id',
            db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.date',
            'invoiceid',
            get_sql_select_client_company(),
            'paymentmode',
            'transactionid',
            'note',
            'amount',
        ];
        $where = [
            'AND status != 5',
        ];

        $custom_date_select = $this->get_where_report_period(db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.date');
        if ($custom_date_select != '') {
            array_push($where, $custom_date_select);
        }

        $by_currency = $this->input->post('report_currency');
        if ($by_currency) {
            $currency = $this->currencies_model->get($by_currency);
            array_push($where, 'AND currency=' . $this->db->escape_str($by_currency));
        } else {
            $currency = $this->currencies_model->get_base_currency();
        }

        $aColumns     = $select;
        $sIndexColumn = 'id';
        $sTable       = db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords';
        $join         = [
            'JOIN ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices ON ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.id = ' . db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid',
            'LEFT JOIN ' . db_prefix() . 'clients ON ' . db_prefix() . 'clients.userid = ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.clientid',
            'LEFT JOIN ' . db_prefix() . 'payment_modes ON ' . db_prefix() . 'payment_modes.id = ' . db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.paymentmode',
        ];

        $result = data_tables_init($aColumns, $sIndexColumn, $sTable, $join, $where, [
            'number',
            'clientid',
            db_prefix() . 'payment_modes.name',
            db_prefix() . 'payment_modes.id as paymentmodeid',
            'paymentmethod',
            'deleted_customer_name',
        ]);

        $output  = $result['output'];
        $rResult = $result['rResult'];

        $footer_data['total_amount'] = 0;
        foreach ($rResult as $aRow) {
            $row = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
                if (strpos($aColumns[$i], 'as') !== false && !isset($aRow[$aColumns[$i]])) {
                    $_data = $aRow[strafter($aColumns[$i], 'as ')];
                } else {
                    $_data = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
                }
                if ($aColumns[$i] == 'paymentmode') {
                    $_data = $aRow['name'];
                    if (is_null($aRow['paymentmodeid'])) {
                        foreach ($payment_gateways as $gateway) {
                            if ($aRow['paymentmode'] == $gateway['id']) {
                                $_data = $gateway['name'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!empty($aRow['paymentmethod'])) {
                        $_data .= ' - ' . $aRow['paymentmethod'];
                    }
                } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.id') {
                    $_data = '<a href="' . admin_url('payments/payment/' . $_data) . '" target="_blank">' . $_data . '</a>';
                } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.date') {
                    $_data = _d($_data);
                } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == 'invoiceid') {
                    $_data = '<a href="' . admin_url('invoices/list_invoices/' . $aRow[$aColumns[$i]]) . '" target="_blank">' . format_invoice_number($aRow['invoiceid']) . '</a>';
                } elseif ($i == 3) {
                    if (empty($aRow['deleted_customer_name'])) {
                        $_data = '<a href="' . admin_url('clients/client/' . $aRow['clientid']) . '" target="_blank">' . $aRow['company'] . '</a>';
                    } else {
                        $row[] = $aRow['deleted_customer_name'];
                    }
                } elseif ($aColumns[$i] == 'amount') {
                    $footer_data['total_amount'] += $_data;
                    $_data = app_format_money($_data, $currency->name);
                }

                $row[] = $_data;
            }
            $row[]= $this->get_items($aRow['id']);
            $output['aaData'][] = $row;
        }

        $footer_data['total_amount'] = app_format_money($footer_data['total_amount'], $currency->name);
        $output['sums']              = $footer_data;
        echo json_encode($output);
        die();
    }
}
```

[image]

It appears that no data is being displayed. Could you please provide guidance on what might be incorrect in my approach?

Comment: Anyone can look into it?